# Webservice Throws InstanceAlreadyExistsException in Service Mix 5.0

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, jetty, apache-servicemix

We are using Apache Camel, Service Mix and Smooks for our project and it contains multiple modules. Each will be deployed as bundle in servicemix.

We are Using the Webservices in some of the modules.

We are Using jaxws WebService in following ports 9191,9192,9193,...

When i deploy the second webservice bundle in ServicMix, it throws the following exception.

Kindly Advice to overcome this.

```
2014-05-28 11:29:15,570 | WARN  | tenderThread-270 | MBeanContainer                   | ?                                   ? | 53 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.9.v20130131 | bean: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@3a30285e
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.eclipse.jetty.server:type=server,id=0
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.addBean(MBeanContainer.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.add(MBeanContainer.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.add(Container.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.update(Container.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.update(Container.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.setConnectors(Server.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.addConnector(Server.java:173)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:304)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:49)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:95)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:893)[136:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:131)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:362)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)[73:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[115:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_40]
2014-05-28 11:29:15,582 | WARN  | tenderThread-270 | MBeanContainer                   | ?                                   ? | 53 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.9.v20130131 | bean: SelectChannelConnector@172.21.30.131:9195
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio:type=selectchannelconnector,id=0
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.addBean(MBeanContainer.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.add(MBeanContainer.java:146)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.add(Container.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.update(Container.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.update(Container.java:111)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.setConnectors(Server.java:199)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.addConnector(Server.java:173)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:304)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:49)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:95)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:893)[136:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:131)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:362)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)[73:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[115:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_40]
2014-05-28 11:29:15,590 | WARN  | tenderThread-270 | MBeanContainer                   | ?                                   ? | 53 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.9.v20130131 | bean: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection@3abda9b1
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler:type=contexthandlercollection,id=0
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)[:1.7.0_40]
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.jmx.MBeanContainer.addBean(MBeanContainer.java:298)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.Container.addBean(Container.java:182)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.setServer(AbstractHandler.java:80)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setServer(HandlerCollection.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.setHandler(HandlerWrapper.java:81)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPServerEngine.addServant(JettyHTTPServerEngine.java:369)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http_jetty.JettyHTTPDestination.activate(JettyHTTPDestination.java:179)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractObservable.setMessageObserver(AbstractObservable.java:49)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.AbstractBaseBindingFactory.addListener(AbstractBaseBindingFactory.java:95)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapBindingFactory.addListener(SoapBindingFactory.java:893)[136:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-bindings-soap:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:131)[130:org.apache.cxf.cxf-api:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.doPublish(EndpointImpl.java:362)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:251)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:539)[144:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:2.7.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_40]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_40]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[:1.7.0_40]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1608)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)[71:org.springframework.beans:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)[73:org.springframework.context:3.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$1600(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:69)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:355)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)[114:org.springframework.osgi.core:1.2.1]
        at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)[115:org.springframework.osgi.extender:1.2.1]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)[:1.7.0_40]
2014-05-28 11:29:15,598 | INFO  | tenderThread-270 | Server                           | ?                                   ? | 53 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.9.v20130131 | jetty-7.6.9.v20130131
2014-05-28 11:29:15,602 | WARN  | tenderThread-270 | MBeanContainer                   | ?                                   ? | 53 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 7.6.9.v20130131 | bean: qtp1425958650{8<=0<=0/254,-1}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's the similar issue like in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-4878.
There is mentioned that in jetty 8.1.14 this problem is solved.

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: In the url it is fixed in 8.1.14 and 2.7.8. Bue the Version of CXF in ServiceMix 5.0 is 2.7.10. http://servicemix.apache.org/downloads/servicemix-5.0.0